# PHP Manual Example #6 Static variables with recursive functions variation scope understanding

Tags: php, function, recursion, static-variables

Apologies in advance (newbie here), but trying to understand and having a tough time finding a topic directly related to this. I'm made a variation of Example #6 Static variables with recursive functions from the php manual

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
<?php

    function test() {
        static $count = 0;
        $count++;
        echo $count;
        if ($count < 10) {
            test();
        }
        $count--;
        echo $count;
    }
    
    test();

?>
```

Output is 123456789109876543210

I would expect it to stop after it goes to 9 outside of the if statement and is decremented.
(e.g.)123456789109

I'm obviously not understanding static scope and code flow. I really should figure out a debugger going forward, but any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this little modification helps you to understand better.

Why doesnt it stop after it goes to 9 outside of the if statement?

Because every call of test runs test till the end. It is been incremented 10 times and it is been decremented 10 times. First increment it 10 times because of 10 calls of test and in the 10th call the decementing beginns. The 10th call is finished and the 9th call decrements. The 9th call is finished and the 8th call decrements....

```
<?php
function test()
{
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;
    echo $count.". call of test() (output after incrementing)<br />";
    if ($count < 10) {
        test();
    }
    echo $count.". call of test() (output before decrementing)<br />";
    $count--;
}

test();
?>
```

Output:

```
1. call of test() (output after incrementing)
2. call of test() (output after incrementing)
3. call of test() (output after incrementing)
4. call of test() (output after incrementing)
5. call of test() (output after incrementing)
6. call of test() (output after incrementing)
7. call of test() (output after incrementing)
8. call of test() (output after incrementing)
9. call of test() (output after incrementing)
10. call of test() (output after incrementing)
10. call of test() (output before decrementing)
9. call of test() (output before decrementing)
8. call of test() (output before decrementing)
7. call of test() (output before decrementing)
6. call of test() (output before decrementing)
5. call of test() (output before decrementing)
4. call of test() (output before decrementing)
3. call of test() (output before decrementing)
2. call of test() (output before decrementing)
1. call of test() (output before decrementing)
```